# How to convert a mwb schema in Java entities for Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How can I convert a schema that I have in Sql Workbench to Java entities for Hibernate?

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I would first generate the SQL script from MySQL WorkBench, then physically create the schema in a local database instance.

You can then generate the Hibernate entities direct from the database.

Plenty of guides online for this last step. E.g. http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/